# OpenRefine: How to delete content of cells if it matches specific string pattern?

Tags: regex, data-cleaning, openrefine, grel

So I'm doing my first project in OpenRefine and I don't fully get the GREL thing and how to transform my proeject with it yet...

Problem is: I have a column in which I want to delete ONLY the contents of the cells that match a specific pattern and ONLY if they contain nothing else.

My column looks like this: (image not allowed)

```
LF 2(1927)40
 
LF 2(1927)42
 
"Wirtin" LF 2(1927)44
 
Lottchen LF 3(1928)3
 
LF 3(1928)7
 
"Mit schönem Gruß Arthur Powalla aus Hamburg" LF 3(1928)9
 
LF 3(1928)14 DF 3(1927)1
```

I want to delete the content of all the cells that contain ONLY a string pattern like `LF 2(1927)42`. If they contain more than that, I want to keep everything and not delete that pattern.

In the Transform... menue of that column I tried to use the following GREL command:

`if(value==(LF \d\(\d*\)\d+),null,value)`

I used the regular expression included in this before for a different operation, and it did what it was supposed to do. So I assume the mistake lies elsewhere.
The error it sends is this:

`Parsing error at offset 14: Missing )`

Thanks so much for helping me on this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern matching on assignment or comparison expressions is a feature that is not supported by GREL.

The expression you are looking for is

```js
if(isNull(value.match(/LF \d\(\d*\)\d+/)), value, null)
```

Note that I am telling GREL to use the [match](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grelfunctions#matchs-p) function on the content of the cell (`value`) and try to apply the regular expression, enclosed in `/`.

We then differentiate between `null` (pattern does not apply) and an empty array (the pattern does apply, but the pattern does not have a sub pattern defined) via [isNull](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grel#isblanke-isnonblanke-isnulle-isnotnulle-isnumerice-iserrore).

Alternatively you could also use a [text filter](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/facets#text-filter) with regular expressions and then perform a transformation on the filtered data. This is more intuitive when you are not that familiar with GREL.